# Variable URL Reference in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a dashboard for work that has a bunch of information, including unique links for each of our clients. I am trying to write a script that will open the url in a new window when a button is clicked. However, I need that URL to change based on the client that we have selected.

Here is the code I have written. It's bad, like really bad, but I am stuck on how I should do this.

```
var SPREADSHEET_NAME = "Database";
var SEARCH_COL_IDX = 0;
var RETURN_COL_IDX = 0;

function openLink() {
  
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("Dashboard"); //Form Sheet
  
  var str       = formSS.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var values    = ss.getSheetByName("Database").getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    if (row[0] == str) {

      var html = "<script> window.open(ss.getValue(row[1]));</script>";
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html)
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui,"Loading");

  }
 }
}
```

Here is a link to a Google Sheet that shows at a very basic level how I want this function to work. Dropdown in B2 on the Dashboard, when I select a "link" and press the button, the URL associated with the option I selected in B2 (that is in the database tab) will open.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1edKkHluCk3o0x96sQ7cw-cHcMBUnXzaOiPoywJA6Dyc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to open new window when the script of `openService` is run.
- You want to retrieve the value from the cell "B2" of "Dashboard", and want to open the URL from "Database" using the retrieved value.

#### Modification points:

- Unfortunately, `"<script> window.open(ss.getValue(row[1]));</script>"` cannot be directly run. In this case, I would like to propose to set the URL to `window.open(URL)` in the script.
- The flow of the modified script is as follows.

  1. Retrieve the value from cell "B2" of "Dashboard".
  2. Retrieve the values from "Database".
  3. Create an object for searching the URL.
  4. Retrieve the URL using the object and open new window.

When above flow is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function openService() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  // 1. Retrieve the value from cell "B2" of "Dashboard".
  var formSS = ss.getSheetByName("Dashboard");
  var str = formSS.getRange("B2").getValue();
  
  // 2. Retrieve the values from "Database".
  var [, ...values] = ss.getSheetByName("Database").getDataRange().getValues()
  
  // 3. Create an object for searching the URL.
  var obj = values.reduce((o, [a, b]) => Object.assign(o, {[a]: b}), {});
  
  // 4. Open new window.
  if (obj[str]) {
    var html = `<script>window.open("${obj[str]}"); google.script.host.close();</script>`;
    var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html)
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui,"Loading");
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, after the new windows was opened, the dialog is closed using `google.script.host.close()`. If you don't want to close the dialog, please remove it.
- Please use this script with enabling V8.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [Window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)